# How do I trigger a dropdown button blur / close event on bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to trigger an event after a buton group is closed (to catch mutiple changes inside that button group).

```
<div class="btn-group">

<span id="experiment-filter-group" class="btn-group pull-right open">
<button type="button" style="width:auto" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-small" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Here <b class="caret"></b></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
      <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0;"><label style="margin:0;padding:3px 20px 3px 20px;width:100%;height:100%;cursor:pointer;"><input style="margin-bottom:5px;" type="checkbox" value="0"> X Option</label></a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0;"><label style="margin:0;padding:3px 20px 3px 20px;width:100%;height:100%;cursor:pointer;"><input style="margin-bottom:5px;" type="checkbox" value="1"> Y Option </label></a></li>
</ul>
</span>

</div>

<script>
    $('.btn-group').on("closed", function(e){
            console.log("closed");
        });
</script>
```

this is not working..

Comment: Do you mean button dropdown menus?

Comment: yes dropdown-toggle I am using  https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect and I need to know when the user has finished selecting values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no twitter bootstrap dropdown on close event, but you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btn-group').data('open', false);

    $('#dropdown-button').click(function () {
        if ($('#btn-group').data('open')) {
            $('#btn-group').data('open', false);
            onCloseEvent();
        } else $('#btn-group').data('open', true);
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
        if ($('#btn-group').data('open')) {
            $('#btn-group').data('open', false);
            onCloseEvent();
        }
    });

    function onCloseEvent() {
        alert("close");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Barbarah/QYvJh/3/